# Where should I declare a variable from one class to be used in another?

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I have two classes, Window and CustomerInfo. The Window class displays a login user interface where the user will enter a valid username and password into textFields. I have written code which correctly accepts correct username and passwords and rejects wrong information. If the information is correct, the CustomerInfo class opens with multiple textFields for user information such as name, address, phone number, etc. This user information is stored in a SQLite database which I am pulling from when the user logs in and setting those textFields with the appropriate previously entered and saved information.

As you can see I am using a SELECT FROM statement to access this information. I need to include a WHERE clause that will pull from whichever username was entered (e.g. SELECT FirstName FROM CustInfo WHERE Username = username). The username variable will be whichever user logged in. I am trying to set that variable by String username = textFieldUsernameCust.getText(); I do not know where to declare this variable statement as the textFieldUsernameCust text box is in the Window class and I need to use this variable in the CustomerInfo class.

Window class...

```
public class Window {

    private JFrame frame;
    public static JTextField textFieldUsernameCust;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Window window = new Window();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Connection connection=null;
    public JPasswordField passwordFieldCust;
    public JTextField textFieldUsernameComp;
    public JPasswordField passwordFieldComp;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Window() {
        initialize();
        connection=sqliteConnection.dbConnector();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 619, 377);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
        lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblUsername.setBounds(86, 166, 86, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
        lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblPassword.setBounds(86, 202, 65, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

        textFieldUsernameCust = new JTextField();
        textFieldUsernameCust.setBounds(182, 165, 97, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldUsernameCust);
        textFieldUsernameCust.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnLoginCust = new JButton("Login (Customer)");
        btnLoginCust.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String query="select * from CustomerInfo where Username=? and Password=?";
                    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, textFieldUsernameCust.getText() );
                    pst.setString(2, passwordFieldCust.getText() );

                    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
                    int count=0;
                    while(rs.next()){
                        count=count+1;
                    }
                    if (count==1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful");
                        frame.dispose();
                        CustomerInfo custinfo=new CustomerInfo();
                        custinfo.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else if(count>1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate Username or Password");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or Password is incorrect. Please try again");
                    }

                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();

            } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }


            }
        });
        btnLoginCust.setBounds(116, 259, 117, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLoginCust);

        JLabel lblWelcome = new JLabel("Welcome to InsurU");
        lblWelcome.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 20));
        lblWelcome.setBounds(221, 46, 232, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblWelcome);

        passwordFieldCust = new JPasswordField();
        passwordFieldCust.setBounds(182, 201, 97, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordFieldCust);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Username:");
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        label.setBounds(329, 168, 86, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Password:");
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        label_1.setBounds(329, 204, 65, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label_1);

        textFieldUsernameComp = new JTextField();
        textFieldUsernameComp.setColumns(10);
        textFieldUsernameComp.setBounds(425, 165, 97, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldUsernameComp);

        JButton btnLogincompanyt = new JButton("Login (Company)");
        btnLogincompanyt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String query="select * from CustomerInfo where UserName=? and Password=?";
                    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, textFieldUsernameComp.getText() );
                    pst.setString(2, passwordFieldComp.getText() );

                    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
                    int count=0;
                    while(rs.next()){
                        count=count+1;
                    }
                    if (count==1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful");
                        frame.dispose();
                        CompanyInfo compinfo=new CompanyInfo();
                        compinfo.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else if(count>1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate Username or Password");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or Password is incorrect. Please try again");
                    }

                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();

            } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }
            }
        });
        btnLogincompanyt.setBounds(374, 259, 117, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogincompanyt);

        JLabel lblCustomerLogin = new JLabel("Customer Login");
        lblCustomerLogin.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblCustomerLogin.setBounds(116, 107, 117, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCustomerLogin);

        JLabel lblCompanyLogin = new JLabel("Company Login");
        lblCompanyLogin.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblCompanyLogin.setBounds(374, 108, 117, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCompanyLogin);

        passwordFieldComp = new JPasswordField();
        passwordFieldComp.setBounds(425, 201, 97, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordFieldComp);
    }
}
```

CustomerInfo class...

```
public class CustomerInfo extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textFieldFirstName;
    private JTextField textFieldLastName;
    private JTextField textFieldAdress;
    private JTextField textFieldCity;
    private JTextField textFieldZipCode;
    private JTextField textFieldEmail;
    private JTextField textFieldNumber;
    private JTextField textFieldAge;
    private JTextField textFieldUsername;
    private JTextField textFieldPassword;
    private JTextField textField_10;
    private JTextField textField_11;
    private JTextField textField_12;
    private JTextField textField_13;
    private JTextField textField_14;
    private JTextField textField_15;
    private JTextField textField_16;
    private JTextField textField_17;
    private JTextField textFieldAnnualCar1;
    private JTextField textField_19;
    private JTextField textField_20;
    private JTextField textFieldAnnualCar2;
    private JTextField textField_22;
    private JTextField textField_23;
    private JTextField textFieldAnnualCar3;
    private JTextField textFieldTotalDrivers;
    private JTextField textField_26;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CustomerInfo frame = new CustomerInfo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public CustomerInfo() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 623, 382);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(10, 11, 593, 327);
        contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Profile", null, panel, null);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First Name:");
        lblFirstName.setBounds(26, 26, 65, 14);
        panel.add(lblFirstName);

        textFieldFirstName = new JTextField();
        textFieldFirstName.setBounds(92, 23, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textFieldFirstName);
        textFieldFirstName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblAdress = new JLabel("Adress:");
        lblAdress.setBounds(26, 51, 46, 14);
        panel.add(lblAdress);

        JLabel lblDOB = new JLabel("Date of Birth:");
        lblDOB.setBounds(26, 155, 76, 14);
        panel.add(lblDOB);

        JLabel lblRelationship = new JLabel("Relationship Status:");
        lblRelationship.setBounds(310, 186, 96, 14);
        panel.add(lblRelationship);

        JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("E-mail:");
        lblEmail.setBounds(26, 211, 46, 14);
        panel.add(lblEmail);

        JLabel lblPhone = new JLabel("Phone Number:");
        lblPhone.setBounds(310, 211, 76, 14);
        panel.add(lblPhone);

        JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name:");
        lblLastName.setBounds(204, 26, 65, 14);
        panel.add(lblLastName);

        textFieldLastName = new JTextField();
        textFieldLastName.setBounds(270, 23, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textFieldLastName);
        textFieldLastName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblCityAdress = new JLabel("City:");
        lblCityAdress.setBounds(26, 76, 46, 14);
        panel.add(lblCityAdress);

        JLabel lblStateAdress = new JLabel("State:");
        lblStateAdress.setBounds(26, 101, 46, 14);
        panel.add(lblStateAdress);

        JLabel lblZipCode = new JLabel("Zip Code:");
        lblZipCode.setBounds(26, 126, 46, 14);
        panel.add(lblZipCode);

        textFieldAdress = new JTextField();
        textFieldAdress.setBounds(92, 48, 264, 20);
        panel.add(textFieldAdress);
        textFieldAdress.setColumns(10);

        textFieldCity = new JTextField();
        textFieldCity.setBounds(92, 73, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textFieldCity);
        textFieldCity.setColumns(10);

        textFieldZipCode = new JTextField();
        textFieldZipCode.setBounds(92, 123, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textFieldZipCode);
        textFieldZipCode.setColumns(10);

        JComboBox comboBoxState = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxState.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Al", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"}));
        comboBoxState.setBounds(92, 98, 46, 20);
        panel.add(comboBoxState);

        JComboBox comboBoxDBMonth = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxDBMonth.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"}));
        comboBoxDBMonth.setBounds(92, 152, 46, 20);
        panel.add(comboBoxDBMonth);

        JComboBox comboBoxDBDay = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxDBDay.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"}));
        comboBoxDBDay.setBounds(141, 152, 37, 20);
        panel.add(comboBoxDBDay);

        JComboBox comboBoxDBYear = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxDBYear.setBounds(182, 152, 65, 20);
        panel.add(comboBoxDBYear);

        textFieldEmail = new JTextField();
        textFieldEmail.setBounds(92, 208, 130, 20);
        panel.add(textFieldEmail);
        textFieldEmail.setColumns(10);


        JComboBox comboRelationshipStatus = new JComboBox();
        comboRelationshipStatus.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Married", "Single", "Divorced", "Widowed", "Domestic Partners"}));
        comboRelationshipStatus.setBounds(422, 183, 86, 20);
        panel.add(comboRelationshipStatus);

        textFieldNumber = new JTextField();
        textFieldNumber.setBounds(422, 208, 122, 20);
        panel.add(textFieldNumber);
        textFieldNumber.setColumns(10);

        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection connection=null;
        connection=sqliteConnection.dbConnector();
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Gregory\\workspacefinal\\Customer.sqlite");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Adress, City, ZipCode, Email, PhoneNumber, Age FROM CustomerInfo WHERE Username = username");

                String firstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
                String lastName = rs.getString("LastName");
                String adress = rs.getString("Adress");
                String city = rs.getString("City");
                String zipcode = rs.getString("ZipCode");
                String email = rs.getString("Email");
                String phonenumber = rs.getString("PhoneNumber");
                String age = rs.getString("Age");

                textFieldFirstName.setText(firstName);
                textFieldLastName.setText(lastName);
                textFieldAdress.setText(adress);
                textFieldCity.setText(city);
                textFieldZipCode.setText(zipcode);
                textFieldEmail.setText(email);
                textFieldNumber.setText(phonenumber);
                textFieldAge.setText(age);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, CustomerInfo looks like it is doing more than the name implies. It's extending JFrame which means it's part of the view. You should reflect this in the class name.

Consider passing the username to the constructor of CustomerInfo.

Answer (score 1):

This mixing of gui logic and application logic is terrible.

Your main function should be structured as follows:

1. Invoke a separate method which does all the necessary gui gimmicks to prompt the user for user name and password and returns them in a `LoginInfo` class specially created to hold a username and a password.
2. If no response was given, (user cancelled,) terminate.
3. Invoke another separate method which does all the necessary gui gimmicks to prompt the user for the remaining information and returns this information in a `CustomerInfo` class specially created to hold that info. (Do NOT call your dialog `CustomerInfo`.  The dialog should be called `CustomerInfoDialog`.)
4. If no response was given, (user cancelled,) terminate.
5. Update the database with the information.

A gui function returning null instead of an actual `LoginInfo` or `CustomerInfo` object implies that the user cancelled.

Comment: Your points are excellent; however, they do not answer the question of the OP of how to pass the login info to the other class.

Comment: I assumed my logic and structure was going to be pretty off. This is my first experience with a GUI and I welcome any suggestions and criticisms! At this point, I am just trying to make the program run as intended.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I wrote: "[...] In order to receive responses back from your gui, you need to declare two new classes: 1. A LoginInfo class to hold a username and password, [...]"  So, you pass the login info "to the other class" by returning a `LoginInfo` object.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I can see why it may have been unclear; I will amend my answer.

Comment: Yes, the OP still does not know "where to declare his variable".

Comment: @QuantumQuarks: Try to combine the two answers. Put the login info in a LoginInfo class. Add a LoginInfo parameter to the constructor of the (now renamed) `CustormerInfoDialog` class and create it like this: `CustomerInfoDialog custinfoDlg = new CustomerInfoDialog(theLoginInfo);`

Comment: Thank you Mike and Olivier! Olivier, would you be able to show me an example of your last statement using the parameters from my code above? I have tried to set up a renamed CustomerInfoDialog class and pass the LoginInfo into the parameter, but I am having trouble getting the class to compile. What LoginInfo exactly will be the parameter?